# Disnake/Discord.py Button is not responding, with my callback function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, disnake

So I've been trying to get disnake buttons to get to work, for a good amount of time, and I am ending up with "This Interaction Failed", and it doesn't even execute the callback function i defined within the derived class of `disnake.ui.button`. There are no errors so i cannot debug whats wrong, It would be appreciated if anyone can point out if there are any problems.

**Not**e: qna is a global variable. I've posted the relevant sections below.

```py
class QueryButton(disnake.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, choice: int, user_id: str, label=None, style=disnake.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id=None):
        super().__init__(label=label, style=style, custom_id=custom_id)
        self.choice = choice
        self.user_id = str(user_id)

    async def callback(self, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        queries = qna["users"]["id"][self.user_id]["queries"][-5:]
        query_number = str(queries[str(self.choice-1)])
        query = qna["queries"]["id"][query_number]

        embed = disnake.Embed(title=f"Query for {query['user']}", color=0xff0000)
        embed.add_field(name="Question", value=query["question"], inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Answer", value=query["answer"], inline=False)

        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)


# list of buttons as components (this is inside a slash command)
buttons = [QueryButton(choice=str(i), user_id=user_id, label=str(i), style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id=str(i)) for i in range(1, len(queries)+1)]
await interaction.followup.send(embed=embeds, components=components)
```

Edit: I've added logging and here is what gets logged when I click a button.

```
2022-10-25 00:51:17,821:DEBUG:disnake.client: Dispatching event socket_event_type
2022-10-25 00:51:17,822:DEBUG:disnake.client: Dispatching event message_interaction
2022-10-25 00:51:17,822:DEBUG:disnake.client: Dispatching event button_click
2022-10-25 00:51:17,822:DEBUG:disnake.client: Dispatching event interaction
2022-10-25 00:51:28,202:DEBUG:disnake.gateway: Keeping shard ID None websocket alive with sequence 17.
2022-10-25 00:51:28,263:DEBUG:disnake.gateway: For Shard ID None: WebSocket Event: {'t': None, 's': None, 'op': 11, 'd': None}
```

Comment: change [logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html) and you should see more information when you run it in console/terminal

Comment: @furas edited the post in question, to add your comment.

Comment: Any reason you're using `disnake` and not just the buttons that are already built-in to discord.py?

Comment: @stijndcl been using purely disnake, just added discord.py cause both seems to be awfully similar.

Comment: Disnake is a fork of discord.py so obviously it's quite similar.